# Transform coordinate to EPSG:4978 fails

Tags: postgis, proj

I am trying to transform a geometry to the EPSG:4978 projection. As the EPSG:4978 was missing in the `spatial_ref_sys` table, I have added it using the following query:

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 4978, 'epsg', 4978, '', 'GEOCCS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137.0,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["m",1.0],AXIS["Geocentric X",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Y",EAST],AXIS["Geocentric Z",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4978"]]');
```

Source: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-2/postgis/

When I however try to use the projection in one of my queries, it fails with:

```
ERROR: AddToPROJ4SRSCache: could not parse proj4 string ''
```

With Proj4js the empty string definition works just fine, so it seems to me that Postgis should handle the empty string case as well. Or am I misunderstanding something specifically about EPSG:4978? What is the proper way to transform a coordinate to EPSG:4978?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Looks like there is an error in the statement at the link you provided, with the SRID being 94978, it should be:</strike>

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 4978, 'epsg', 4978, '', 'GEOCCS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137.0,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["m",1.0],AXIS["Geocentric X",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Y",EAST],AXIS["Geocentric Z",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4978"]]');
```

My PostGIS version 2.2.2 rl14797 has the following data for 4978:

> srid = 4978
>
> auth_name = "EPSG"
>
> proj4text = "+proj=geocent +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "
>
> srtext = "GEOCCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS
>   84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Geocentric
>   X",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Y",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric
>   Z",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4978"]]"

Comment: `gdalsrsinfo epsg:4978` outputs the same strings, at least for GDAL 2.1.0

Comment: I also noticed the strange SRID value for the provided query.... That's why I already changed the value. Will try again with your proj4 definition.

Comment: the srtext I have is also a bit different but probably wont affect anything because the spheroid is the same